# Capture log4J output with grep

Tags: bash, scripting, log4j, grep, stderr

I know that log4j by default outputs to stderror.

I have been capturing the out put of my application with the following command:

```
application_to_run 2> log ; cat log | grep FATAL
```

Is there a way to capture the output without the auxiliary file?

Comment: If you did need to use the temp file for some reason, `cat` is unnecessary: `app 2> log; grep FATAL log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both `stdout` and `stderr`, use:

```
( application_to_run 2>&1 ) | grep FATAL
```

If you want both `stderr` alone, you can use:

```
( application_to_run 2>&1 >/dev/null ) | grep FATAL
```

The first sends all output destined for file handle 2 (`stderr`) to file handle 1 (`stdout`), then pipes that through `grep`. The second does the same but also sends `stdout` to the bit bucket. This will work since redirection is a positional thing. First, `stderr` is redirected to the *current* `stdout`, then `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: This seams to do the trick. I was wondering that is the point of the brackets (subshell?) as well

Comment: Just habit on my part, probably not necessary in `bash` - I come from an age where the original Bourne shell was the latest and greatest. Although modern shells have far more advanced features (and less gotchas), I still find myself often reverting to the old ways. In fact, I can't even remember if there _was_ a positional problem in the early shells. It may just have been something from my mentors at the time. Way too close to retirement to start changing now :-) By all means test it without the subshell. If it works, it will save some wear-and-tear on your fingers and keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to redirect *stderr* to *stdout* so you can use it in a pipe, there are two ways I know of:

```
$ command 2>&1 | ...

$ command |& ..
```

Comment: and as paxdiablo says, "2>&1 >/dev/null" will leave you only with the stderr and discard the stdout.